# Packing density of randomly deposited circles on a plane

Tags: pr.probability, packing-and-covering, geometric-probability

Let's say that I have a rectangular two-dimensional surface of bounded dimensions, $[0,A]$ and $[0,B]$:

Under "no overlap" constraints, I sequentially deposit circles of radii $r_c$ on this surface, where the center-point of each circle is allowed real number coordinates and is chosen with uniform probability. To address concerns related to edge conditions, only the center-point of each surface needs to be on the bounded plane.  If a set of random coordinates imply an overlap with one or more previously deposited circles, a new set of random coordinates is chosen.  Under no conditions may any of the previously placed circles be rearranged.

Under these conditions, approximately how many circles, $N$, should I be able to pack onto the plane?  What average-case maximum packing density is achievable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The model you describe seems to fall under what's called **"Random Sequential Addition"** or **"Random Sequential Adsorption"** in the literature; it's viewed as a higher dimensional analogue of the car parking problem.  An early review in the physics literature on this type of model by J W Evans is [here](https://doi.org/10.1103/RevModPhys.65.1281).  From this review, I found [a paper by Einar L. Hinrichsen, Jens Feder and Torstein Jøssang](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01011908) which discusses continuum RSA of disks in the plane.  Their simulations yield that for large A,B the fraction of space filled in the jammed state is around $\theta_J=0.5472\pm0.002$, from which you should be able to extract the answers to your questions.

There's a newer review [here](https://doi.org/10.1088/0953-8984/19/6/065124) by A Cadilhe, N A M Araújo and Vladimir Privman.

There's a ton of more recent work, but this should give you a place to start looking.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is essentially equivalent and slightly more symmetric if you make the rectangular surface "wrap around". (I'm assuming you want to have $A,B\gg r_c$?) You can of course also scale the problem so that $r_c=1$.

Assuming this the number of circles that you can place scales like $cAB$. I very much doubt that you can get a closed form for $c$, but you can get some simple bounds: Certainly $c\le 1/\pi$ (in fact you can get a better upper bound by looking at the best packing of discs in the plane: hexagonal tiling) so that you have $n\le AB/\pi$.

You can get a lower bound also: Supposing you've got a maximal packing of circles with centres $C_1,C_2,\ldots,C_n$. Then let $B_1,\ldots,B_n$ be discs of radius 2 about $C_1,\ldots,C_n$. These must cover the region (if any point is left out then you can add a new circle centred at that point without overlapping any of the original circles). 
Since they cover you get $4\pi n\ge AB$ so that $n\ge AB/(4\pi)$.

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in a physicist's point of view on the question, you might like to look at [Random Heterogeneous Materials, S. Torquato](http://cherrypit.princeton.edu/book.html). It is now a little bit dated, but it provides a very extensive list of references.